# Segue-ing to Embedded view controller

Tags: ios, segue

I have have a view controller that is embedded in a UINavigationController and I want to segue to another view controller that is also embedded in a different UINavigationController. If I try to use a push segue, I get an error saying that I can't push a UINavigationController. However, I don't think using a modal segue is appropriate. How should I go about this?

Comment: Why do you have the second controller embedded in its own navigation controller? If you need both navigation controllers, then a modal segue is the best option.

Comment: @rdelmar I did this for UI reasons (to make sure the navigation bar is at the same height throughout the app)

Comment: One navigation controller should show the same height navigation bar height as you push new controllers. You don't need to use more than one to do that.

Comment: but the problem is that I want different bar button items for each view controller and they won't change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How should I go about this?

You should use a single navigation controller.

> the problem is that I want different bar button items for each view controller and they won't change

Each view controller can set up the bar buttons however it likes. Take a look at [`UINavigationItem`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationItem_Class/). Each view controller has a navigation item, and the navigation item has various properties such as `leftBarButtonItems` and `rightBarButtonItems` that you can use to set the buttons.

Comment: so do I have to add a navigationItem from the IB onto the view controller or can I just do "self.navigationItem..."? because the latter doesn't work. and I just added a navigationItem to the storyboard from the IB and connected it and that did not work either

Comment: You can do it in IB or in code -- both techniques do work. If it's not working in your app, there's a problem with your code or storyboard. Edit your question to include your code and maybe someone will spot your error.